# Disable LDAP authentication on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, ldap, authentication

I have an Ubuntu server that is able to authenticate users against our Domain. I can not contact the person who set this up, but I do find these packages installed:

`libaprtil1-ldap`
`libldap-2.4-2`
`samba`

Our server is taking a good minute or so to authenticate ANY user at this point. I believe that it is because one of our DCs was disabled a couple weeks ago. This causes many programs I use to timeout before successfully authenticating. I do not want to uninstall anything, as I do not want to make more work for our admin. I just need some suggestions on how I can disable this in the meantime, until things can get fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick way to disable LDAP authentication is to remove any `ldap` sources from `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.